# How do I suppress warning messages in my knitted Rmd file

Tags: r, r-markdown, warnings

I've made some code and transferred it into an Rmd file in order to be knitted into a word document. The code I'm using is functional, however due to the size of the data there are quite a few warnings that fill the docx. They look as such:

`1: In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion`

I was wondering if there is a way for these not to be expressed in the final knitted docx.

I've tried `{r messages = FALSE}` but I can't see any other options.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `warning=FALSE` as well?

Answer (score 2):

There are options available to control how each chunk in your RMarkdown code behaves.

As you've noted,

```` ```{r message=FALSE} ````

in the first line of the chunk will suppress messages. To add other display options, you need a comma after the first option:

```` ```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE} ````

In your case, you might also need `message=FALSE`.

A full list of the R Markdown display options is available in the [R Markdown cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf)

which you can also access through your RStudio IDE, menu "Help/Cheatsheets>R Markdown Cheat Sheet"

Comment: See also [Chunk options and package options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/). Note that it is *error*, *warning* and *message*, NOT *errors*, *warnings* or *messages*. The latter won't work!